# Powershell change part of file names within one subfolder( byfolder name) within a folder

Tags: powershell

I'd like to bulk rename files filtered by folder name.

I have used the following code

```
dir .\* -include "*Plantegninger*"-recurse| Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "-00K-","-00U-"}
```

In the above code the files I want to replace, part of name, are in subfolder named "Plantegninger"
I want to change -00K- to -00U-
I have many sub folders with this name within sub folders in my main folder. Therefore I'm trying to do this recursively.
But I believe this is filtering by filename and not sub folder name.
How do I filter by sub folder name, then change file name only within sub folders of that particular name?
Also can I filter by sub folder name and then by filename within that sub folder?

Comment: Do you want to rename only files _immediately_ under the named subfolder(s), or do you want to recurse to the bottom of each named subfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split the operation into two distinct steps it becomes easier to reason about:

1. Enumerate all subfolders with the given name
2. Rename relevant files in each subfolder

```bsh
# enumerate relevant sub folders
$subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Filter '*Plantegninger*' -Directory -Recurse

# rename files in subfolders 
$subfolders |Get-ChildItem -File |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "-00K-","-00U-"}
```

Once you have it working as intended, you can always combine the statements to a single pipeline again (if desired - I personally find it more readable with separate statements):

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*Plantegninger*' -Directory -Recurse |Get-ChildItem -File |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "-00K-","-00U-"}
```